Capturing errors from output of a command, detecting them in text processing pipeline
the following section of a bash (RHEL 7) script invokes a SELECT SQL on the Ingres sql command, if the query is successful, returns results in text format with a log of the query itself, followed by results separated by pipes. There is a pipeline to capture the actual tabular output and save in CSV, format the dates, etc.
sql $HBDB <<_END_ | grep '^|' | sed -E 's/^\|//; s/\|$//; s/ *\| */","/g; s/^ *| *$//g; s/^/"/; s/$/"/; s/#//g; s;([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4});\1/\2/\3;g' > $OUTFILE1
    set autocommit on;
    \p\g
    set lockmode session where readlock = nolock;
    \p\g
    select * from table
    \p\g
 _END_

However, occasionally there is an typo/error in the SQL we're running which causes the output file to be empty. This is frustrating because the actual reason for the error is contained in the output alongside an error code, but this is all being stripped out by the pipeline. So we have to manually remove the pipeline from the script, and try again, to see the details of the error.
I wanted to try and check for the presence of the error code in the pipeline (denoted by "E_" appearing at the start of a line) and if so, send the whole output (not just that line) to a file path stored in $ERRLOG variable (so after runtime, we can check the error log easily). However, I am struggling to get this to work, the following code is not working, the ERROLOG file is empty
 sql $HBDB <<_END_ | tee >(grep '^E_' && cat > $ERRLOG && exit 1) | grep '^|' | sed -E 's/^\|//; s/\|$//; s/ *\| */","/g; s/^ *| *$//g; s/^/"/; s/$/"/; s/#//g; s;([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{4});\1/\2/\3;g' > $OUTFILE1
    set autocommit on;
    \p\g
    set lockmode session where readlock = nolock;
    \p\g
       /* errant query */
    selet * from table_which_does_not_exist
    \p\g
 _END_

I thought this would check the output for the "E_" text at start of any line, and if so send whole output to the ERRLOG and exit the script, but this is not happening, all outputs are empty and the exit 1 command is not being invoked.
The reason I wan to do this in a pipeline is because we have scripts which invoke the sql command a lot, and save outputs to CSV, and I want as little code as possible.

Regarding "I want as little code as possible" - why? If this is stored as a script (and it should be) then what difference does it make how much code is in that script?

Are you SURE the error message when a failure occurs is contained alongside the stdout and not in a different stderr stream?

@EdMorton the error message is in the stdout (as far as I can make out, Im not sure how I'd know if it was stderr? its just in the data that is passed over into the pipeline, same as successful results wouldn be)

I wouldn't try to do this all in one line as a pipeline, just keep it simple with a temp file, e.g. untested:
tmp=$(mktemp) || exit
trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; exit' EXIT

sql "$HBDB" <<_END_ > "$tmp" 2>&1; rslt="$?"
    set autocommit on;
    \p\g
    set lockmode session where readlock = nolock;
    \p\g
       /* errant query */
    selet * from table_which_does_not_exist
    \p\g
_END_

if (( rslt == 0 )); then
    grep '^|' "$tmp" | sed ... > "$OUTFILE1"
else
    cat "$tmp" >> "$ERRLOG"
fi

The above assumes you have/want all stdout and stderr together in a single output stream from the sql command, as indicated in the question.
